# Cutting tubes with defined lengths (Bin Packing with a Constant Number of Item Types)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, job-scheduling

Suppose I have an order for small tubes of different types a1...a10 and I have infinite amount of large tubes with the same length I have to cut with minimal waste so that I can produce the ordered amount of small tubes. Which optimization algorithm would apply to my problem?

Comment: Please clarify the problem statement. From the current formulation you could simply cut all small tubes from one large tube. Or is some bound on the length of the large tubes given as part of the input?

Comment: This reads a lot like homework...

Comment: This reads a lot like the Bin Packing problem.

Comment: Believe it or not this is the actual problem. A friend working with metal asked me to help him minimize waste. It's been almost 10 years since I left the University and all I came up with is that it's kind of a scheduling problem. My friend has tubes of 6 meter and orders for example for 20 x 20cm, 50x 1.5m and so on. I figured it's a known amount of jobs with defined work and a number of processors to work all the jobs in any order minimizing the idle time and number of processors. Since there is some waste cutting metal a job switch overhead in the algorithm would be nice too :)

Comment: Is it still Bin Packing when I have to cut more then one tube into smaller ones and I have to produce all small tubes?

Comment: Oh I did some reading on Bin Packing and it seems to be the correct solution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Codor pointed out, this is a Bin Packing problem. At least it is a subclass there of: There is another category called the "Cutting Stock" Problem, where the "weight" of the material is categorized in couple of discrete categories and is not continuous value.

The bin packing problem is a NP Problem which mean the optimal solution(s) can be found by trying out all possible solutions. As for the cutting stock: it is more constrained and there is a polynomial solution algorithms discovered by Thomas Rothvoss (or Rothvoß). I didn't understand it yet but if someone is interested there is a paper called "Polynomiality for Bin Packing with a Constant Number of Item Types" and a Youtube video [Better Algorithms for Bin Packing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy45-JH8_yY). Unfortunately I haven't found yet a source code implementing the algorithms.